# How to use YouTube IFRAME-Player in localhost html file?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I am writing an HTML-only app and want to embed a YouTube IFRAME-based player. I used the demo code from https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference unfortunately, this does not seem to work out-of-the-box for HTML files loaded via the file://  protocol. I get the following error:

> www-widgetapi.js:100
>
> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').

I found [Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': https://www.youtube.com !== http://localhost:9000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573017/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-https-www-youtube-com-http) unfortunately it didn't help: whether I include it using their JS file via http or https doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not use your own IFRAME but instead let the YouTube API create the IFRAME -> no problems whatsoever. Don't know why though, so if anyone is able to elaborate I'd be interested.

Edit, some sample code, although it's a few years old:

```
let player = new YT.Player('gv-player-iframe', {
          height: playerHeight,
          width: playerWidth,
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
            'onError': onPlayerError
          }
        });
```

Comment: if this works would be useful to give an example

Comment: Added my sample code from back in the days, however, the code is almost 6 years old and hasn't been used by myself for quite some time now, don't know if it still valid. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, you are running it through your file system. Instead try using local host.

For more information read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710842/google-api-in-javascript)

Comment: I've found that as well ... thing is, I don't want to run a local web server. The app should be HTML only.

Comment: @D.R. You can have a HTML only app running on localhost. E.g. today's PWA's in development mode do just that most of the time.