# google authentication using javascript fails

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Trying to use the gapi function to implement a google authentication (oauth2) but the code below fails

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function handleClientLoad() {
        // Loads the client library and the auth2 library together for efficiency.
        // Loading the auth2 library is optional here since `gapi.client.init` function will load
        // it if not already loaded. Loading it upfront can save one network request.
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      function initClient() {
        // Initialize the client with API key and People API, and initialize OAuth with an
        // OAuth 2.0 client ID and scopes (space delimited string) to request access.
        gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: 'APP_ID',
            discoveryDocs: ["https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"],
            clientId: 'CLEINT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            scope: 'profile'
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
        });
      }

      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        // When signin status changes, this function is called.
        // If the signin status is changed to signedIn, we make an API call.
        if (isSignedIn) {
          makeApiCall();
        }
      }

      function handleSignInClick(event) {
        // Ideally the button should only show up after gapi.client.init finishes, so that this
        // handler won't be called before OAuth is initialized.
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      function handleSignOutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      function makeApiCall() {
        // Make an API call to the People API, and print the user's given name.
        gapi.client.people.people.get({
          'resourceName': 'people/me',
          'requestMask.includeField': 'person.names'
        }).then(function(response) {
          console.log('Hello, ' + response.result.names[0].givenName);
        }, function(reason) {
          console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
    <button id="signin-button" onclick="handleSignInClick()">Sign In</button>
    <button id="signout-button" onclick="handleSignOutClick()">Sign Out</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

and shows an error

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [link](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/issues/443), you might get that error if the iFrame has not loaded and you can ignore it if everything still works, as it makes more than one attempt to communicate. It can happen if the target site has forgotten to include the content window script file.

Also from this thread: [Google API in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710842/google-api-in-javascript)

> Based on the error you're receiving, my guess is that you either do not have your Javascript Origin configured properly on the [Google API console](https://cloud.google.com/console/) you got your Client ID from, and/or you are trying to run your script from the file system instead of through a web server, even one running on `localhost`.  The Google API client, near as I've been able to tell, does not accept authorization requests from the file system or any domain that has not been configured to request authorization under the supplied Client ID.